# Overriding default SWIG name for static class functions

Tags: c++, lua, swig

I have several classes that I am using swig to wrap for an embedded Lua script. We have already defined what we want the function calls to look like.

```
display.writeLine("Hello")
```

The problem is that SWIG doesn't seem to have an option to define how it generates the library name. The c++ class looks like this.

```
class Display
{
public:
    static void writeLine(char *);
}
```

I can easily get SWIG to wrap this function, it's just that always shows up like this
    Display_writeLine()

So instead of just using my custom namespace, I would have to do

```
display.Display_writeLine()
```

which is not what I want. I have tried experimenting with the rename rules but nothing seems to work. Right now I have an extern C function that then calls my static function but it's an extra call I don't need. Seems like it should be something simple...

Answer (score 2):

You can easily make a shortcut for your function that does same of function code and load the file on start:

```
display = {}

function display.writeline(str)
      display.Display_writeLine(str)
end
```

Comment: yeah I'm basically doing something like that right now but I thought there may be a cleaner solution